# Can not install pandas on windows 64 bit

Tags: python, windows, pandas, pip

Trying to install pandas on a new windows 64 system. I did so using:

```
pip install pandas
```

the installtion aborts with error when trying to install pytz (from pandas):

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytz (from pandas)

Trying to import pandas falis with error:

> Cannot import name hashtable

How can I over come it? Or should I just install the 32 bit version of pandas?

Answer (score 0):

I used to have a lot of installation issues when I tried to manually create my own Python environment. I run Windows 7 64-bit and would suggest you download and try to install any one of these:

- https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/
- https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/

Comment: Ill try that as a last resort... currently, this is the only package i failed to install.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running CPython you can try to install it using the windows binaries available here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pandas

You can find several binaries, for different Python version and x64/win32. It also has a link to it's dependencies (like pytz) if you don't have them all.
My complete windows Python environment was built based on that.

Comment: What is CPython and how do I know if i run it? I install python 2.7.5 in the usuall way.. If you mean that a C python is a python with packages compiled in C++, then the answer is yes, I used MSVC

Comment: CPython is the Python you get from [Python.org](http://www.python.org/download/) website. It's  just the name given to the Python implementation based in C. If you built it yourself I belive it will still work, but I didn't built mine so I can't confirm.

Comment: Well, it didnt work because of the pytz which pip cannot install. In the link you gave me I see an installation for that package and others, but i might eventually just take a complete build like anaconda and such..

Comment: have you tried installing pytz before? downloading the binary from that website?